# Tabulator library and undo function

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I am trying to add row menu and header menu to my table.Both functions works fine , but function undo does not working and function userTable.getHistoryUndoSize() allways returns 0. Undo works fine when I editing data in table manually only.
Can someone help what I am doing wrong?
I am using latest tabulator 4.8.3

Thank you

```
var rowMenu = [{
    label:"Enable All Floors",      
    action:function(e, row){
        userTable.blockRedraw();                                                                    
        row.update({f1:true});row.update({f2:true});row.update({f3:true});row.update({f4:true});row.update({f5:true});row.update({f6:true});
        row.update({f7:true});row.update({f8:true});row.update({f9:true});row.update({f10:true});row.update({f11:true});row.update({f12:true});
        row.update({f13:true});row.update({f14:true});row.update({f15:true});row.update({f16:true});
        userTable.restoreRedraw();                                                                  
    }       
},
{
    label:"Disable All Floors",                                                                     
    action:function(e, row){
        userTable.blockRedraw();                                                                            row.update({f1:false});row.update({f2:false});row.update({f3:false});row.update({f4:false});row.update({f5:false});row.update({f6:false});
        row.update({f7:false});row.update({f8:false});row.update({f9:false});row.update({f10:false});row.update({f11:false});row.update({f12:false});
        row.update({f13:false});row.update({f14:false});row.update({f15:false});row.update({f16:false});
        userTable.restoreRedraw();                                                                  
    }
}
]

var headerMenu = [{
    label:"Set All in column to ON",
    action:function(e, column){
        userTable.blockRedraw();                                                                    
        rows.forEach(function(row){
            row.update({AL :true});                                                         
        }); 
        userTable.restoreRedraw();                                                                  
    }
},
{
    label:"Set All in column to OFF",
    action:function(e, column){
        userTable.blockRedraw();                                                                    
        rows.forEach(function(row){
            row.update({AL:false});                                                                 
        }); 
        userTable.restoreRedraw();                                                                  
    }
}]

dataChanged:function(data){
    console.log("data in table edited");    
    document.getElementById( 'undoBadge' ).innerHTML = userTable.getHistoryUndoSize();
    document.getElementById('BTNundoData').removeAttribute("disabled");
    PreventLoseData = true;                                                                
},
```

Comment: Without seeing your table in action it is hard to offer advice. Please post a link to a JS fiddle that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: As a side note you shouldn't call row update repeatedly like that it is extremely inefficient. You should call it once and pass in a single object with all the properties you want to change

Comment: -create new user and edit name or id or access, all changes are counted inside undo button,But when you right click on row and change whole row at "one shot", counting and undo does not works.What I am doing wrong?

Comment: That is because the row.update function is not tracked through the history system, only edits to cel data is tracked

Comment: Thank you.Do you plan to add this feature to your library in future?

Comment: No, the history function is intentionally only related to user interactions with the table not all programmatic calls to the api

Comment: Ok, thank you for answer!